# Nested for loop to multiply two lists by two variables python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested

I'm importing a CSV file into Python, then performing least squares regression with the x and y values. So far my program:

- opens CSV file and delimits at commas
- creates two lists consisting of X and Y (x_list and y_list, respectively)
- calculates the average of all the values of X, and does the same for all the 
  values of Y (x_avg and y_avg, respectively)

I'm having trouble finding the numerator of the slope:

> sum((Xi - X avg) * (Yi - Y avg))

I'm using a nested for loop but am getting an incorrect result back for my m_num (slope numerator).

```
def compute_numerator(x_list, y_list, x_avg, y_avg):
    m_num = 0                                                                                                                                 
    xi = []
    yi = []
    multiples = []
    xi = [(x - x_avg) for x in x_list]
    yi = [(y - y_avg) for y in y_list]
    for x in xi:
        for y in yi:
            multiples = [x * y]
    m_num = sum(multiples)
    print(m_num)
    return m_num
```

I need m_num to return the sum of all the values of (X - the average of X) * (Y - the average of Y)

Any suggestions or critiques welcome! Trying to learn and also pick up good programming habits. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't need explicit loops for any of this except reading the file maybe, including average, which is just `sum(list_x) / len(list_x)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want each (x, y) value in `x_list`,`y_list` paired up with each other, this would work:

```
sum((x-x_avg)*(y-y_avg) for x, y in zip(x_list, y_list))
```

Your problem is that you're not pairing them, and instead having each x value sum with all y values, like so:

```
sum((x-x_avg)*(y-y_avg) for x, y in x_list for y in y_list)
```